# Redux - Updating state variable on checkbox toggle (and rerendering component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

**edit:** For those looking for a solution, please look at my submitted solution below.

```
  Show:
  {" "}
  <FilterLink filter="SHOW_ALL">
      All
  </FilterLink>
  {", "}
  <FilterLink filter="HIDE_DUPLICATES">
      Duplicates
  </FilterLink>
</p>
```

I'm writing a Redux app that will update the state when a checkbox is checked. Right now I'm working on getting the store to update correctly when the checkbox is checked.

The problem I'm encountering right now is I'm not properly dispatching the `toggleDuplicates` action from `containers/GlossaryControls.js`.

A copy of the code can be [**found here**](https://bitbucket.org/DigitalMockingbird/redux-checkbox-sandbox/src).

Thanks in advance for the help!

**actions/actions.js**

```
const toggleDuplicates = (filter) => {
  return {
    type: "TOGGLE_DUPLICATES",
    filter
  };
};

export default toggleDuplicates;
```

**reducers/data.js**

```
let words = [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "english": "woof",
    "french": "le woof"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "english": "woof",
    "french": "le woof"
  }];

export default words;
```

**reducers/toggleDuplicates.js**

```
const toggleDuplicates = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "TOGGLE_DUPLICATES":
      return state; // duplicate removal logic will go here
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default toggleDuplicates;
```

**reducers/index.js**

```
import {combineReducers} from "redux";
import words from "./data.js";
import toggleDuplicates from "./toggleDuplicates";

const allReducers = combineReducers({
  words,
  toggleDuplicates
});

export default allReducers;
```

**containers/GlossaryControls**

```
import React from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import toggleDuplicates from "../actions/actions";

let GlossaryControls = (props) => {
  return (
        <div>
          <input
              type="checkbox"
              checked={this.props.toggleDuplicates}
              onChange={toggleDuplicates}
          />
          {" "}
          Hide duplicates
        </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    toggleDuplicates: ownProps.toggleDuplicates === state.toggleDuplicates
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    onClick: () => {
      dispatch(toggleDuplicates(ownProps.toggleDuplicates))
    }
  };
};

const FilterDuplicates = connect (
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(GlossaryControls);

export default FilterDuplicates;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those looking for a solution, I ended up passing the filter type into a container as keys. The code looks similar to this:

```
  Show:
  {" "}
  <FilterLink filter="SHOW_ALL">
      All
  </FilterLink>
  {", "}
  <FilterLink filter="HIDE_DUPLICATES">
      Duplicates
  </FilterLink>
</p>
```

In my code, I needed to send the key (filter) to a container function, which then correctly wired up the components via `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`.

```
const getVisibleEntries = (words, filter) => {
  switch (filter) {
    case "SHOW_ALL": {
      return words;
    }
    case "HIDE_DUPLICATES": {
      return words;
    }
    default: {
      return words;
    }
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  words: getVisibleEntries(
      state.words,
      state.toggleDuplicates
  )
});

const mapDispatchToProps = ({
  onEntryClick: toggleDuplicates
});

const VisibleGlossary = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(GlossaryTable);

export default VisibleGlossary;
```

Answer (score 1):

[`createStore`](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/api/createStore.md) is incorrect.

> reducer --> initialState --> middleWare

NOT

> initialState --> reducer  --> middleWare

Because `initialState` is optional and isn't required for redux unlike reducers.

```
createStore(
    toggleDuplicatesReducer,
    initialState,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(createLogger())
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is returning the same state everytime :

```
const toggleDuplicates = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "TOGGLE_DUPLICATES":
      return [...state,action.state];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

export default toggleDuplicates;

```
 <input
              type="checkbox"
              checked={this.props.onclick}
              onChange={toggleDuplicates}
 />
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply Codesingh. Returning the same state is intentional for now. The error I'm encountering is the reducer is not receiving an action.type from the action `toggleDuplicates`. Am I sending the dispatch incorrectly from the checkbox in GlossaryControls or does it have to do something with the action?

Comment: please check the edit and reply me if it does not work for you

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting the error: `toggleDuplicates.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
    at toggleDuplicates (toggleDuplicates.js:2)`. I'm looking at my `mapDispatchToProps` in `GlossaryControls` right now to see if that's the troubled area.

Comment: I added my `actions` file to the above code as well, if that helps.

Comment: what are you trying to do at onchange in input tag

Comment: When the checkbox is toggled, the status of the box is sent to the toggleDuplicates. If it's checked, it should return the modified state (no duplicates), if not checked, it should return the initial state.

Comment: have you defined export type State at the top of reducer?

Comment: do like this inside reducer

Comment: export type State = {data:boolean};const initialState = {data:false} and then export default function (state:State = initialState, action:Action): State{
    if (action.type === 'TOGGLE_DUPLICATES') {
        return {
          ...state,
           data:action.data
                  };
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131493/discussion-between-codesingh-and-digitalmockingbird).

Comment: In action do this : export function toggleDuplicates (data:boolean){
    return {
        type: "TOGGLE_DUPLICATES",
         data:data
    }
}